# Different responses for the same GET call

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So I have a Get API that retrieves all the tables in a given database. I was using Insomnia to test and I receive the intended results as seen here:
[Insomnia Successful call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQsJG.png)
However, when I try to do the exact same thing in my react app, I get a different response ("No tables") and I have no idea why.
My react code:

```
            axios.get("http://localhost:3001/Invoices/tables", { 
          dbType: "MS SQL Server",
          dbName: "MMPOS",
          username: "sa",
          password: "KNb@2020",  
          host: "CPQ"
          })
```

Comment: is your endpoint getting the data from the body of the request?

Comment: Yea, since they are used to connect to the database and retrieve the tables. All tables get retrieved in Insomnia. This means that my backend or endpoint is working correctly. But for some reason, it won't work with the request from react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving this response because the second param that Axios.get allows you to send is not the body of the request, it's a config object since it's a GET request.

Example:

```
axios.get('/users', {
 params: {
  userId: '123'
 }
});
```

I believe you have two options: you can either change your HTTP method to be a post, so you can send a request body or you can keep the GET method and use query string params to send the data.

Comment: Thank you. The params solution did not work but changing it to a post method worked!